# How to pull SharePoint data in Outlook add-in?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an add-in for Outlook that needs to pull data from SharePoint. Unfortunately I haven’t found any definitive approaches to how the add-in can take a session (Exchange) and make a request to SharePoint without having the user sign on again (to the SharePoint).

It should work in the following configurations:

1. On-Prem: SharePoint & Exchange 2013 & 2016
2. Hybrid:  SP Azure & Exchange 2013 & 2016
3. O365: SP & O365 both in cloud

Any suggestions/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there isn't a way to grab a token for the current session.

The most effective way to accomplish what you need is kick off an OAUTH workflow from within the add-in. Once you have that token, you can use it against either Graph or SharePoint APIs.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to promote the current Outlook/OWA token to OAuth?

Comment: I'm afraid not but the ability to get a token that works with Graph is on the roadmap. You can see the spec for this functionality on [GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/Addin_SSO_OpenSpec). Please keep in mind that this is still in the design/preview stage so it isn't suitable for production deployments just yet yet.

Comment: Is there a way to get the SharePoint online auth token (no graph) using Outlook token?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marc

Tom, the functionality is expected to be in limited preview by mid-may so not suitable for prod deployment till late in the year however keep in mind it will only work with 
O365: SP & O365 both in cloud because it depends on Azure AD. For Hybrid and on-prem you will need to do as Marc suggested.